# Function to change Days to Years

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a function to convert days to years.
In my data set, the Age of my customers is given in days instead of years.
I do not have any other information about their Age. (No DOB)

This is one of the solutions I have tried:

```
def convert (age_in_days):
    Age = int[(age_in_days/365)]
    return Age
    convert (['age_in_days'])
```

and then calling the function with

```
convert(data['age_in_days'])
```

my output is:

```
[id
 1        31.041096
 2        83.038356
 3        44.024658
 4        65.021918
 5        53.041096
            ...    
 79849    70.013699
 79850    46.019178
 79851    68.041096
 79852    30.024658
 79853    54.027397
 Name: age_in_days, Length: 79853, dtype: float64]
```

as you can see I have a total of 79853 observations

1. when I try to convert to a data frame so I can append to my main data set,
   pd.DataFrame(Age, columns = ['age'])
   this is what I get:

```
            age
age_in_days NaN
```

And nothing else, I need to add the calculated values of age to my data set.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is any requirement to write a separate function to convert days to years.

We can do the same directly in pandas as

**Sample Input DF**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[11, 12],
    'age_in_day':[22643, 10262]
})

    id  age_in_day
0   11  22643
1   12  10262
```

**Two Options**

**Option 1 - Code - Pandas way**

```
df['age_in_years'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.age_in_day, unit='D') / np.timedelta64(1,'Y')
```

**Output**

```
    id  age_in_day  age_in_years
0   11  22643       61.994428
1   12  10262       28.096402
```

**Option 2 - Code - float div**

```
df['age_in_years'] = df['age_in_day'] / 365
df
```

**Output**

```
    id  age_in_day  age_in_years
0   11  22643       62.035616
1   12  10262       28.115068
```

**Other options**

By any means if we have a separate `list/Series`(generated from an external function) of `age in years` which we want to add to existing df. Then

**Series**

```
0    62.035616
1    28.115068
Name: age_in_day, dtype: float64

df['age_in_years'] = age_Series
```

**List**

```
age_list=[62.035616438356165, 28.115068493150684]
df['age_in_years'] = age_list
```

Comment: nw, all the best!